# Vue.js. Получение props в динамических компонентах. Как правильно?

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Добрый день. Возник вопрос связанный с props и динамическими компонентами Vue.js (без vue-router). Использую vue-cli для старта и vue-resource для запросов на сервер.

Общая схема такова: есть родитель который запрашивает данные с сервера и передаёт их через `props` дочерним компонентам. Так же он переключает компоненты.

Изначально я делал последовательное переключение компонентов. Первый компонент у меня слушал значение `props` с помощью `watch` и когда данные там появлялись, они копировались в `data` компонента. Далее при определённых условиях родитель переключал на следующий компонент. В нём уже не было нужды слушать с помощью `watch` значения в `props`, так как они уже там точно есть и я в хуке `Created` вызывал метод который их копировал в `data` компонента. И так в следующем и в следующем. Но вот когда я решил отказаться от последовательности, возникли некоторые сложности. Первое что я сделал, это добавил во всех дочерних компонентах `watch` слушающие `props`, который в свою очередь вызывал метод копирования в `data` компонента. Такой подход позволил первым запустить любой компонент, но при переключении на другой, вызова функции копирования не происходило, так как определение вызова метода находилось в `watch` слушающем изменения `props`. Однако props на этот момент уже имеет свои данные и они не меняются, следовательно `callback` у `watch` не вызывается. Я попробовал добавить вызов метода копирования в хуке `Created`, но получил ошибку. И это логично, так как при загрузке первого компонента данных для копирования ещё нет.

Немного поэкспериментировав я нашел вариант решения этой задачи. 
Это создание события в потомке с помощью `$emit()` которое запускает в родителе метод получения данных с сервера. Далее родитель передаёт их через props потомку, а тот в свою очередь слушает с помощью `watch` изменения `props`. Это работает и позволяет первым запустить любого потомка, но при их переключении опять происходит событие которое вызывает метод родителя на получение данных с сервера. Чтоб не создавать ненужную нагрузку на сервер и не запрашивать опять данные которые уже есть я ограничил кол-во исполнения тела функции до одного раза. Теперь сколько бы события не вызывали метод, он исполнится единожды при первом вызове. Но вот при переключении компонентов опять сталкиваюсь с проблемой. Функция копирования в потомке не запускается так как её вызов находится в `watch`. Единственное что приходит в голову, это создать вспомогательную переменную в данных передаваемых через `props` и ложить в неё уникальное значение при каждом событии генерируемом в потомке. Это заставит срабатывать `watch` у потомков.

Однако мне кажется что это не очень правильное решение. Очень смахивает на костыли ). Хотел спросить у знающих, как правильно решить эту задачу?

Спасибо!

правка:
Придумал ещё один вариант. Вызов функции копирования в компонентах помещаем в `watch` и в хук `created` с условием, если в `props` не пусто то вызываем, а если там пусто, значит это первый запуск компонента и мы ждём пока данные придут с сервера. `watch` их отловит и вызовет функцию копирования. Это работает, но на сколько это жизнеспособно и правильно? Хотелось бы увидеть варианты как это можно реализовать по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props не нужно копировать в data, это точно такой же источник реактивных данных в том же неймспейсе (экземпляре Vue), что и data; data - это контекст, который не выходит за пределы компонента, а props - это отфильтрованный родительский контекст. Их свободно можно использовать в шаблоне, и он будет реагировать на изменения, просто в отличие от data props нельзя установить (точнее, можно, но родитель этого не заметит):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <proof v-bind:prop="entry" />
</div>
<script type="application/ecmascript">
Vue.component('proof', {
  template: '<div>{{ prop }}</div>',
  props: ['prop']
})
var app = new Vue({el: '#target', data: {entry: 0}})
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  app.entry = app.entry > 8 ? 0 : app.entry + 1 
}, 1000)
</script>
```

Если же вам все-таки необходимо по каким-то причинам копировать props, то вы можете либо создавать элементы, но держать их скрытыми, либо использовать связку this.$props / this.$options.propsData в created/beforeCreated плюс описанный watch